# How to pass values to another UINavigationViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIViewController, and i have to pass a value (UIImage, NSString) to an UINavigationViewController, I am using

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    AppDetail *advc = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        advc.appTitel = name;
        advc.appIcon = icon;
        advc.detailAppName = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
        advc.appDeveloper = developer;
    }
}
```

to pass the value to the `UIViewController`, it works perfectly if I pass it directly to a `UIViewController`, but I can't pass it to a `UINavigationViewController`,
Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: You could if you subclass UINavigationController in the same way you subclass UIViewController

Comment: @bandejapaisa OK, how?

Comment: You should not subclass UINavigationController.  You can use `advc.navigationController` or, more ideally, create a separate object to manage data handling (so the view controllers can focus on display).

Comment: @AaronBrager You're probably right in most cases, however from the UINavigationController class documentation "This class is generally used as-is but may be subclassed in iOS 6 and later." His case is pretty straightforward, so I can't see any future issues by subclassing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this sample code from an Apple segue example. Perhaps it helps.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Room Create"]) {
        // Prepare the settings view where the user inputs the 'serviceType' and local peer 'displayName'
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
        SettingsViewController *viewController = (SettingsViewController *)navController.topViewController;
        viewController.delegate = self;
        // Pass the existing properties (if any) so the user can edit them.
        viewController.displayName = self.displayName;
        viewController.serviceType = self.serviceType;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem days ago

Answer (score 0):

To pass value using `Segue` in your case with a UINavigationController try the code below :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        AppDetail *advc = (AppDetail *)navController.topViewController;

        advc.appTitel = name;
        advc.appIcon = icon;
        advc.detailAppName = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
        advc.appDeveloper = developer;
    }
}
```

If you don't use a UINavigationController, you need to use this following code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

       // Get reference to the destination view controller
        AppDetail *advcc = segue.destinationViewController;

        advc.appTitel = name;
        advc.appIcon = icon;
        advc.detailAppName = detileName;
        advc.appDescription = description;
    }
}
```